# How to periodically change the content of an HTML block in a Moodle course?

Tags: javascript, html, automation, moodle

I need to display multiple pictures one by one at different time periods in a Moodle course. To that end I'm using an HTML block with one picture at a time (in my first attempt I used a random glossary entry block, which turned out to be an inadequate solution). The HTML block approach is a bit cumbersome as whenever I want to display a different picture I have to manually update the HTML block.
I'd like to have the pictures in the HTML block changed automatically on a daily or weekly basis. Can this even be done? If so, would someone please put me on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key to this question is that you can add javascript to the html block. Thats also why these capabilities are marked with an XSS warning. This is my approach:

1. Add a HTML Block to your Moodle course
2. Add all the pictures you want in the order they should appear on a weekly basis.
3. Depending which editor you are using (most probably atto) find the "html" button the edit the raw text (Help: [MoodleDocs](https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Text_editor#Atto_editor_toolbar_layout)) and click it.
4. Now you can see the `<img>` tags of the pictures you previously added. Add the following javascript to rotate through these pictures on a weekly basis:

```js
<script>
    // Get the week number.
    Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
        var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
        return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);
    }
    var numberofweek = (new Date()).getWeek();

    var parent = document.currentScript.parentNode;
    var pictures = parent.querySelectorAll('img');
    for (var picturenumber = 0; picturenumber < pictures.length; picturenumber++) {
        if (!(numberofweek % pictures.length == picturenumber)) {
            // Hide all pictures that are not mapped to this week.
            pictures[picturenumber].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Cons of this approach:

1. The pictures still get loaded. Some students may find out about this. So don't put any picture in there that should be accessible in the next week.
2. Some students might get different pictures sometimes depending on the timezone of their local machine.

Pros of this approach:

1. You can edit the pictures and the order pretty easy
2. You dont have to install any plugin as `block_html` comes with moodle

Tested on Moodle 3.9.x
The pictures will start from the beginning if there are more weeks than available pictures.

Comment: What do you mean by "Add all the pictures you want in the order they should appear"? Do I have to copy/paste all the images in the "Content" box of the HTML block? This would be a bit cumbersome as I have many images. Is it possible to store the images in "Private files" and read them from there?

Comment: I asked the moodle devs in their telegram chat. I fear that we would need the pluginfile URL for that, which would involve PHP Code. A JS only implementation is out of question here. So to read the pictures from your personal files you would need to implement a seperate block. Or find a block in the moodle plugin directory that does exactly that. But I think thats pretty unlikely. If you have all the pictures on your computer you could drag them all at once into the html block though. If that's not the case the simplest thing probably would be to download all the pictures beforehand.